# Macbook has trouble sending PDFs to print

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook, pdf, printing

I can't seem to send PDFs over a certain size (450Kb) to any printer using my MacBook (Snow Leopard).

Documents that aren't in PDF send fine regardless of size and some small PDFs will send grand.

A google and a look around the print settings hasn't uncovered anything and I was wondering if anyone else had experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the way your printer is connected to your network or MacBook. Could you be descriptive about that part?

Comment: It connects over a company LAN, my machine to a router to the printer.